# Javascript grabbing button inside div with id

Tags: javascript, html

it seems like, when a div tag is added between the following code:

```
 <div id="fixed-drop">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn">Show;</button>
  </div>
```

The following Javascript code is not able to get the item, failing with

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsByClassName')
```

But if that div tag is deleted, javascript is able to grab the button:
I have tried the following js codes:

```
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("fixed-drop").document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");

  var dropdown = document.getElementById("fixed-drop")[0].document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
```

Without div this works:

```
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) can be used to select the child element:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementById("fixed-drop").querySelector('.dropdown-btn');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
});
```

```html
<div id="fixed-drop">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn">Show</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using querySelector you can just combine them `var dropdown = document.querySelector('#fixed-drop .dropdown-btn');`

Comment: I preferred this method because OP used bad chain.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs that you first fetch the div with `document.getElementById("fixed-drop")`. If yor are remove it, the funtion will return null. and the next function cant access null.

**Solution**
Use `querySelector` instead of chaining getElementById() functions.

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn')
console.log('without select parent div:',btn1)

const btn2 = document.querySelector('#fixed-drop .dropdown-btn')
console.log('with select parent div:',btn2)
```

```html
 <div id="fixed-drop">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn">Show;</button>    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove accessing second time to the document.

```html
var dropdown = document.getElementById("fixed-drop").getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");

  var dropdown = document.getElementById("fixed-drop")[0].getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
```

Since getElementById returns a element, you can not access document property on that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use it this way

```
const dropdown = document.getElementById('fixed-drop').getElementsByClassName('dropdown-btn');
```

In addition you should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

<3

Answer (score 0):

```
 var dropdown = document.getElementById("fixed-drop").document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
```

""" document.getElementById("fixed-drop") """ this is an element. You can't
element.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn") on element.

You can use querySelector.

```
var dropdown = querySelector('#fixed-drop .dropdown-btn');
```